# Need to add new column in SQL View and get the value from another row based on condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table where one of the column stores their local language values and I would like to add another column in SQL view which will have values in English only which we can get it from other country.

here's the sample data

| id | country | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Belgium | Product |
| 1 | Italy | Prodotto |
| 1 | Spain | Product |
| 2 | Belgium | Used Car |
| 2 | Italy | Usato |
| 2 | Spain | Used Car |

**Expected Results** :

| id | country | name | English Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Belgium | Product | Product |
| 1 | Italy | Prodotto | Product |
| 1 | Spain | Product | Product |
| 2 | Belgium | Used Car | Used Car |
| 2 | Italy | Usato | Used Car |
| 2 | Spain | Used Car | Used Car |

Please help me with adding new column "English Name" in SQL View which can be derived from other countries. So here, Only Italy will have value other than English so in case Country Italy , I need to get the value from either Beligum/Spain.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use a `CASE` expression, or create a table with the translations and `JOIN` to that?

Comment: How do you know whether a name is an English name or not? Where do those English names come from?

Comment: Why is Italy the only one you need to derive the English name for? Is it *always* Italy for all rows? What if All countries needed to show the English version, where does it come from?

Comment: Please note that given data is sample data .Currently , in my actual data there is only one country which doesn't store english name and in future I know which country stores the English value always..I think we should write query where we apply logic that insert value into all countries based on one country which is always in English such as Belgium

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `FIRST_VALUE` window function to select the name by ordering on when your country is Italy (NULL values are ordered first).

```
SELECT *, FIRST_VALUE(name) OVER(
              PARTITION BY id 
              ORDER     BY CASE WHEN country = 'Italy' THEN 0 END
          ) AS EnglishName 
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fRsAie5u).

Comment: Interesting idea and will work for this few sample data, but that's extremely risky and I really hope the OP can explain a logic which allows a safer way.